# how to repeat string in javascript loop

Tags: string, loops, repeat

I am trying to write a function that simply repeats the string 3 times by making a  loop inside this function:

```
    repeatString('hey', 3) // returns 'heyheyhey'
```

so far I have the following code and am trying to make a loop;

```
    const repeatString = function() {

     }

   module.exports = repeatString
```

Comment: How will the function know how many times to repeat the string? How will it know what the input string is? Take a look at the JavaScript docs at how to define a function, and how to write a simple loop. The examples from the docs should be more than enough for you to progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bit clean way [Repeat function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_repeat.asp)

```
const repeatString = function(str, num) {
     return (num < 0) ? new Error("Error") : str.repeat(num);
 }

module.exports = repeatString
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Code I came up with and worked!

```
const repeatString = function repeatString( str, num) {
str ='hey';
 if (num > 0) {
     return str.repeat(num); 
 } else if (num < 0) {
        return 'ERROR';
    } else {
        return '';
    }


 }


module.exports = repeatString
```